# Increasing the space between grid lines in chart.js?

Tags: javascript, typescript, chart.js

This demo draws grid lines:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-sfxm8f?file=index.ts

How do we space the grid lines and tick labels such that a grid line is only shown for y labels [4,8,12,16,20]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Step Size - Documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html#step-size)

In your case:

```json
        ticks: {
          stepSize: 4,
        },
```

[See result](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-vj3p3p?file=index.ts%3AL78)